# Unable to use 'apt-get update' because of suite value changes at repository on 64-bit raspbian

Tags: raspbian, apt, 64-bit

Thanks, I upgraded and it works now.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93604/raspberry-pi-sudo-apt-get-update-not-working) does this help? It seems to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "short answer" - which often resolves the issue - is to use `apt` instead of `apt-get`. If you're interested in further details, please see [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130946/83790), and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68990841/5395338).

FWIW, the same situation occurred during the RPi OS upgrade to `buster` in 2019. [Here's another solution](http://kraaima.com/inrelease-changed-its-suite-value-from-testing-to-stable-error/) that was discovered then that retains use of `apt-get` - it may still be useful for this upgrade to `bullseye`.